# How can I pass a Visual Studio project's assembly version to another project for use in a post-build event?

Tags: msbuild, variables, parameters, wix, post-build

I have a solution with 2 projects:

- **My Application 1.2.54** (C# WinForms)
- **My Application Setup 1.0.0.0** (WiX Setup)

I would like to add a post-build event to the WiX Setup project to run a batch file and pass it a command line parameter of My Application's assembly version number. The code may look something like this:

```
CALL MyBatchFile.bat "$(fileVersion.ProductVersion($(var.My Application.TargetPath)))"
```

But this results in the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:The expression
>   """.My Application" cannot be
>   evaluated. Method 'System.String.My
>   Application' not found.  C:\My
>   Application\My Application Setup\My
>   Application Setup.wixproj
>
> Error: The expression """.My
>   Application" cannot be evaluated.
>   Method 'System.String.My Application'
>   not found.  C:\My Application\My
>   Application Setup\My Application
>   Setup.wixproj

I would like to be able to pass "1.2.54" to MyBatchFile.bat somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Wix project file (`*.wixproj`) override the `AfterBuild` target to call your batch file :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <!-- Get "My Application" assembly version -->
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="../my_assembly_dir/MyAssembly.dll">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentity"/>
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>

  <Exec Command="MyBatchFile.bat %(AssemblyIdentity.Version)"/>
</Target>
```